# how can i trigger a JPanel to show up in a different application?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a little application in console. The whole thing is yes or no if statements.

Everything is working somewhat perfectly, but the last thing that happens is a `JPanel` pops up with a picture in it.

The rest of the app works and the `JPanel` with the picture in it works but i don't know how to make the `JPanel` to show up, can someone tell me what I should do, plz? ty

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Creating an UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

I order for any component to be showing on the screen, it needs to be attached to some kind of `Window`, for example...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new YourAwesomePanelHere());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: where do i add that, in the JPanel class?

I did i got errors

Comment: Seen as you've seen fit not to supply us with any details about your `JPanel` or the error, I'm not entirely sure how I can help you.  But.  I'd start by checking out the link I supplied and having a look at this line ... `frame.add(new YourAwesomePanelHere());`

Answer (score 0):

when a JPanel draw a image you must repain it ;
test such as:
panel.revalidate();
panel.repain;